# What does contrib stand for in django? and why?

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django. 
I came across the term "contrib" but I don't know what it actually means
It obviously seems from the word "contribution" but why is it named like that?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Contrib name is for software that has been contributed to the project,
>   but which might not actually be maintained by the core developers. 
>   Naming it "contrib" or "Contrib" is a long-established convention, but
>   there's really nothing special about the name, and it's usually only
>   used by fairly large projects. Incase of Django it's a package that
>   contains some of the common functionality required by in web
>   development **[answer copied from below links]**

Batteries included is a jargon that refers to a tool that comes packed with stuff that can get you going immediately.

P.S [for more details have a look here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252053/whats-in-the-contrib-folder) and  [first few lines here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/)

Comment: so it's just like a pack of dependencies assimilated to django? thank you for your answer!:)

Comment: @BangolPhoenix I won't say dependencies, it will be fair to say a collection of utility functions/classed that are commonly used in web development.

Comment: Thank you! Now i can better understand what I'm doing when coding:)